# Explain approximate lines in graph of this function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, graphing-functions, approximation, decimal-expansion

*Sorry that this is a long question; the crux of it is that I want to know why lines appear in the graph of the function ($\varphi^\infty(x)$) I've defined.*

Define $\varphi(x)$ as follows: If the [decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation) of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is $x=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n 10^n$ where $a_n\in\{0,1,2,...,9\}$ and $|\{a_n\;|\;n>0\}|$ is finite let:

$$\varphi(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\left(\max{\{a_k\;|\;k\in\mathbb{N}\}}+1\right)^n$$

(i.e. read $x$'s base $10$ expansion as if it is written in [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) $1+\max{\{a_k\}}$). Then let $\varphi^\infty(x)$ be the value obtained by repeated applications of $\varphi(x)$ until a stable value is reached (if it exists), i.e. $\varphi^\infty(x)=\varphi(\varphi(...(\varphi(x))...))$. To illustrate, $\varphi(57)=57_8=47_{10}$, so $\varphi(57)=47$, and $\varphi(47)=47_8=39_{10}$ so $\varphi(47)=39$, and $\varphi(39)=39_{10}$, so no further applications of $\varphi(x)$ will change it, so $\varphi^\infty(57)=39$. Similarly $\varphi(\frac{1}{3})=0.333..._4=1$ and $\varphi(1)=1$ so $\varphi^\infty(\frac{1}{3})=1$. For any number $y$ with $9$ in its decimal expansion we will obviously have $\varphi(y)=\varphi^\infty(y)=y$; $\varphi^\infty(x)$ seems mathematically irrelevant, but it interests me; when graphed for integer $x$, we get linear patterns.

*Graphs of $\varphi^\infty(x)$ at integer $x$ over increasing domains (full size versions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQs5c.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0BK1.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KDam.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zwxu.png)):*

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

The top line (slope $1$) is numbers containing a $9$; but there are lines of other slopes below (one in red); the following zooms show they are made up of smaller line segments of different slopes.

*Graphs of $\varphi^\infty(x)$ at integer $x$; the first shows the boxed area above, the second is a zoom for large $x$, and the third is a zoom into one of the line segments in the previous graph (full size versions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aih3X.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWNh5.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i85PU.png)):*

[image] [image]

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

At the smallest scale line segments with slope $1$ will occur; this can be seen in $\varphi(x)$ which displays the same pattern (I have only focused on $\varphi^\infty(x)$ because the lines are more obvious).

*Graphs of $\varphi(x)$ at integer $x$ over increasing domains (full size versions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy3r0.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ksq.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLWD9.png)):*

[image] [image]
$\hskip1.7in$[image]

I cannot explain why the points (which on the small scale form short lines of slope $1$) on the large scale arrange themselves approximately into lines of varying slopes passing through the origin. Why do the values of $\varphi^\infty(x)$ and $\varphi(x)$ approximately fit onto clear lines like the ones highlighted above?

I don't know if similar lines occur for non-integer $x$; points where $\varphi^\infty(x)$ is continuous are obviously dense in $\mathbb{R}$; I can't see a good way of plotting $\varphi(x)$ for real $x$ ($\varphi(\frac{2}{3})=0.666..._7=1$ but a computer might give $\varphi(\frac{2}{3})=0.666...7_8\overset{!}{=}0.857..._{10}$). It exists for all integer $x$, but I can't prove $\varphi^\infty(x)$ exists for all $x$ (for some $x$, we might never get a number with $9$ in the decimal expansion).

But my main **question** is the following: *Can anyone explain why the [approximations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zwxu.png) to lines passing through the origin occur in the above graphs? What determines the slope of the lines?*

---

The above graphs were generated by the following python script:

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import *
from fractions import Fraction

def phi(number):
    number=float(number); number=str(number); digits=[]
    for dig in number:
        digits.append(dig)
    digitstest=digits; digitstest.remove('.'); m=int(max(digitstest))+1
    firstdigs=[]
    for dig in number:
        if dig=='.':
            break
        firstdigs.append(int(dig))
    y=0; k=size(firstdigs)-1; n=k
    while n-k<size(digitstest):
        y=y+(int(digitstest[n-k]))*(m**(size(firstdigs)-n+k-1)); k=k-1
    if y-int(y)==0:
        y=int(y)
    return(y)

def phi_infinity(number):
    prev=-1
    while number!=prev:
        prev=number; number=phi(number)
    return(number)

a=int(input("\nLower bound?\n")); b=int(input("\nUpper bound?\n"))
i=linspace(a,b,b-a+1); k=[]
for n in i:
    k.append(phi_infinity(int(n)))
plot(i,k,'.',markersize=3); show()
```